# GEKKO TypeError in python

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko

suppose :

```py
# ww is a numpy array
ww.shape
>>>(10, 1)

# C is a numpy array
C.shape
>>>(5, 10)
```

i want to solve a optimization problem in python with specific objective function.
Here is the code that i wrote for that purpose:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()
x1 = m.Var(value=0.2, lb=0, ub=1, integer=False) #float variable. Lower bound = 0, Upper Bound = 1, inirial Value = 0.2
x2 = m.Var(value=0.2, lb=0, ub=1, integer=False) #float variable. Lower bound = 0, Upper Bound = 1, inirial Value = 0.2
x3 = m.Var(value=0.2, lb=0, ub=1, integer=False) #float variable. Lower bound = 0, Upper Bound = 1, inirial Value = 0.2
x4 = m.Var(value=0.2, lb=0, ub=1, integer=False) #float variable. Lower bound = 0, Upper Bound = 1, inirial Value = 0.2
x5 = m.Var(value=0.2, lb=0, ub=1, integer=False) #float variable. Lower bound = 0, Upper Bound = 1, inirial Value = 0.2

x = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]

# My subjective function
m.Equation(x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 == 1)

# My specific Objective Function
## Remember that I specified about ww and C arrays right upside of these Codes
def Objective(x):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    C_b = np.zeros((1,C.shape[1])) # so C_b.shape would be (1, 10)
    
    for i in range(C.shape[1]):
        for j in range(5):
            C_b[0][i] += math.log10(x[j] * C[j,i])
    
    
    return -sum((C_b * ww)[0])


m.Obj(Objective(x))
m.solve(disp=False)

print(x1.value, x2.value, x3.value, x4.value, x5.value)
```

**Output:**

```py
TypeError: must be real number, not GK_Operators
```

Picture of Error:

[image]

i guess this error is cause of specific objective function! **because** with simple objective functions like :

```py
m.Obj(x1 + x2)
```

I don't get error! so I guess the error comes from specific objective function.

How can I fix this error?
where is the problem?

Comment: Please do not edit solutions into a question. If the problem was solved with the help of an answer, then accept that answer. If you have an alternative solution, then post that as an **Answer**.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel oh,
Okay! the problem is where I **mentioned professor** ?

Comment: Please don't add things like thanks and solved in a title. That is what accepting and upvoting answers are for (and optionally, comments).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel okay excuse me! actually I didn't know about this rules! 
Can I bring back some information **except the [solved] title and things like [thanks] stuff** ?

Comment: As long as it is not a solution, then you can do that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i got it! i should place The solution in **Answer Your Question** Part !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error Fixed by changing the shape of `ww`.
before fixing problem :

```py
ww.shape
>>>(10, 1)
```

fixed The problem with :

```py
ww.shape
>>>(10, )
```

Now proposed algorithm worked without any kind of error or problem. That mean it was cause of shape of `ww`! it fixed after I changed the shape of ww to (10, ) instead (10, 1) .

now Suppose :

```py
# ww is a numpy array
ww.shape
>>>(10, )

# C is a numpy array
C.shape
>>>(5, 10)
```

**Corrected & Proposed Algorithm :**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

nd = 5

m = GEKKO()
x = m.Array(m.Var,nd,value=1/nd,lb=0,ub=1)
m.Equation(sum(x)==1)

i = 0
j = 0
for i in range(C.shape[1]):
    for j in range(C.shape[0]):
        m.Maximize(ww[i]*(m.log10(x[j] *C[j,i])))
        
m.solve(disp=True)
for i,xi in enumerate(x):
    print(i+1,xi.value)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

nd = 5; md = 10
ww = np.random.rand(md)
C  = np.random.rand(nd,md)

m = GEKKO()
x = m.Array(m.Var,nd,value=1/nd,lb=0,ub=1)
m.Equation(sum(x)==1)
for i in range(C.shape[1]):
    for j in range(C.shape[0]):
        m.Maximize(ww[i]*(m.log10(x[j]*C[j,i])))
m.solve(disp=True)
for i,xi in enumerate(x):
    print(i+1,xi.value)
```

The solution is always `1/nd` that is also the same as the initial guess. You can check that the solver converges to this optimal solution (not just stops at the initial guess) by setting the initial guess to something like `1`.

Comment: Why it every time says that optimal solution is `[0.2 , 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]` ?
I Copied your script and just paste it. every run of this cod says that optimal solution is `[0.2 , 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]` . isn't this weird?

Comment: I thought it was weird as well so I used another optimization tool to verify the solution. They both gave the same answer.

Comment: It isn't a problem to add a function with Gekko. Here is an example: https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/blob/master/examples/test_function.py

Comment: You could try this other objective function instead to give different answers for each x: `m.Maximize(ww[i]*(m.log10((x[j]+C[j,i])**2)))`

Comment: Yes i solved this optimization problem with another Package in python and i got same solution.
But Now I'm facing new Error! if i update The topic, can you Check it out please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228599/discussion-between-shayan-and-john-hedengren).

Comment: I updated the code. It may have been a name conflict with `m=10` and `m=GEKKO()`. In your update, there is no definition of `C` or `ww`.

Comment: Thanks Dear Professor,
as you said i edited The topic again. I used your code now but The error still exist.
if I run your code first, and then run it (your script) on my `ww` & `C` then its work. But i should run a copy of your entire code first! that mean probably some values after exacting your code will be save in memory and python use them for executing code with my specific  `ww` & `C` !  
But when i want to execute the code for first time with my `C` & `ww` then the error occurs.
I just Change The `C` & `ww`, and then error occurs. seems there is problem with my `C` and `ww`.

Comment: and This Part of your code should be edited :
`x = m.Array(m.Var, nd, value=1/nd, lb=0,ub=1)`
`n` should be change to `nd`

Comment: Dear Professor Hi,
I fixed The problem and wrote about it in topic **Update 2** !
Thanks For your Help and kindness !

Comment: Posted Here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66185271/11747148.  
Thank You Dear Professor